# Assign a nil to a forced unwrapping optional doesn't crash the code, why is that?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm on the initial way of building a calculator. Currently, the code is doing nothing but printing the digits and Pi into the calculator's label while user taps it.

**1) Che Code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel! = nil //Look Here "(

    var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypeing = false

    @IBAction func touchDigit(_ sender: UIButton){
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypeing {
            let textCurrentlyInDisplay = display.text!
            display.text = textCurrentlyInDisplay + digit
        } else {
            display.text = digit
        }

        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypeing = true
    }

    @IBAction func performOperation(_ sender: UIButton) {
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypeing = false
        if let methematicalSymbol = sender.currentTitle {
            if methematicalSymbol == "π" {
                display.text = String(M_PI) // M_PI
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

**2) UI**

The **touchDigit** function is linked to all the digit buttons as shown in the following figure. The **display** is the `UILable` while **performOperaton** is the PI button

[image]

**Question**: You may found the line (Third line of the code) `UILabel! = nil`. I think adding a `nil` to a forced unwrapping optional would crash the code, but it **doesn't** and so far, the code works fine. Why is that?

Comment: Why do you think it should crash? All optionals (including IUOs) are implicitly initialized to nil, so there is no difference between `var display: UILabel! = nil` and `var display: UILabel!`. *Unwrapping* is what can crash ...

Comment: @MartinR Great, Now I understand it bit better

Comment: Also – assuming that the outlet is correctly connected – the variable will be set when the view controller is instantiated from the Storyboard. So it is not `nil` anymore when `touchDigit` is called.

Comment: @MartinR Yes! you are right. Thanks so much for helping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unwrapped optional is a contract with the compiler that the value won't be `nil` when it is *accessed*. Consider the following playground code.

```
var x: Int! = nil // It's declared as an unwrapped optional *var*
x = 5 // So assigning to it is OK
var y: Int = x // you can access its value, if it's not nil
x = nil // even assigning nil is OK
//y = x // CRASH. *Accessing* it when nil causes an error
```

Adding `= nil` in your declaration is actually spurious - if you dropped it, the variable would still be initialised as `nil`, and, as @MartinR pointed out in comments, your outlet will be assigned to when the Xib is loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice example. I was very confused about the optional concept. Need to continue learning.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare variable as forced unwrapped optional

```
var labelForced: UILabel! = nil
```

all difference from regular optional variable

```
var label: UILabel? = nil
```

is that forced unwrapped optional will always try to implicitly unwrapp when you will try to *get* it value (except case you will mark explicitly safe unwrapp, for example `let text = labelForced?.text`). All other behavior is same

Answer (score 1):

When I look at your UI under point 2 I see that you have connectie the UILabel to a label in your storyboard. Is that correct?
If this is correct, the application doesn't crash when you set it to nil when declaring your UILabel. As soon as the view lifecycle methods are running the UILabel declared and initially set to nil, will be connected to the UILabel in your storyboard.

You can check this by implementing the view lifecycle methods and let it print the UILabel to the console.

Comment: Yes, You are correct, Thanks your guys so much to help me ")